# Set Reference Points for Overlaying Data onto an image in R

Tags: image, r

I have seen a few questions on here (one was even by me) with respect to using R to plot an image.

The difference here is that I need to set the reference cooridnates for my image to match the data I am looking to plot on top of the image.

More specifically, I need R to understand that the coordinates for the background image are `x = (-100,100)` and `y = (40,-40)`.

I have been able to to read in the image file and plot it using the `ReadImages` package, but when I overlay my data using `points()`, the data obviously do not line up appropriately.

Any help is much appreciated.

EDIT:  here are some example data and I attached the image[image]:

```
structure(list(teamid = c("6", "6", "6", "6", "6", "6", "2", 
"6", "6", "6", "2", "6", "10", "10", "10", "10", "20", "20", 
"10", "10", "10", "20", "20", "20", "10", "10"), xcoord = c("79", 
"81", "33", "34", "75", "52", "-67", "80", "44", "79", "-53", 
"54", "-55", "-81", "-66", "-66", "45", "81", "-78", "-70", "-59", 
"50", "53", "63", "-79", "-78"), ycoord = c("0", "0", "-18", 
"-20", "6", "-11", "-7", "7", "-28", "-10", "35", "22", "25", 
"-5", "25", "23", "-11", "13", "22", "16", "13", "23", "7", "16", 
"8", "8")), .Names = c("teamid", "xcoord", "ycoord"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(74328L, 
74331L, 74332L, 74334L, 74336L, 74338L, 74340L, 74341L, 74346L, 
74347L, 74348L, 74349L, 100136L, 100137L, 100138L, 100139L, 100147L, 
100148L, 100151L, 100154L, 100156L, 100158L, 100159L, 100161L, 
100163L, 100167L))
```

Comment: Can you give an example of what you did and what it looks like and what you actually want to achieve. I do not get it.

Comment: You can certainly set image coordinates with the `rasterimage` tools, but I suspect there's an easier way to locate a "background image" for plots. I'll go look around.

Comment: Isn't this what `rasterImage` does? See the examples where it places an image at specific coords.

Comment: Well, now your problem is clear:  you left out the Bruins logo at center ice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create an empty plot with the correct dimensions, then use the `rasterImage` function to plot the image, then adding the points should work fine.

Another approach is to use the `updateusr` function from the `TeachingDemos` package after plotting the image to make sure that the coordinates match what you want them to before adding lines or points.

I saved your graphic above as ice.png and ran the following code:

```
library(EBImage)
ice <- readImage('My Pictures/ice.png')
pos <- structure(list(teamid = c("6", "6", "6", "6", "6", "6", "2",
  "6", "6", "6", "2", "6", "10", "10", "10", "10", "20", "20",
  "10", "10", "10", "20", "20", "20", "10", "10"), xcoord = c("79",
  "81", "33", "34", "75", "52", "-67", "80", "44", "79", "-53",
  "54", "-55", "-81", "-66", "-66", "45", "81", "-78", "-70", "-59",
  "50", "53", "63", "-79", "-78"), ycoord = c("0", "0", "-18",
  "-20", "6", "-11", "-7", "7", "-28", "-10", "35", "22", "25",
  "-5", "25", "23", "-11", "13", "22", "16", "13", "23", "7", "16",
  "8", "8")), .Names = c("teamid", "xcoord", "ycoord"),
 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(74328L,
  74331L, 74332L, 74334L, 74336L, 74338L, 74340L, 74341L, 74346L,
  74347L, 74348L, 74349L, 100136L, 100137L, 100138L, 100139L, 100147L,
  100148L, 100151L, 100154L, 100156L, 100158L, 100159L, 100161L,
  100163L, 100167L)) 
pos$xcoord <- as.numeric(pos$xcoord)
pos$ycoord <- as.numeric(pos$ycoord)

ice2 <- as.raster(ice)

pin <- par('pin')
plot( c(-100,100), c(-40,40), type='n', xlab='', ylab='', 
    asp=pin[1]/pin[2], axes=FALSE, xaxs='i', yaxs='i')
rasterImage(ice2, -100, -40, 100, 40, interpolate=FALSE)
with(pos, text(xcoord, ycoord, teamid, col='green', cex=1.2) )
```

Does this do what you want?

Comment: I was unaware of rasterImage, and with your code example, I was able to get it to work.  Many thanks!