# import xml image into R

Tags: xml, image, r, web-scraping

I would like to import images such as [this](http://pulse.blogs.yandex.net/?size=small&charset=utf8&period=20120116-20130116&query0=%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD) 
, so that i can plot another graph over the image as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4993189/overlay-data-onto-background-image-in-r)  and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9484631/set-reference-points-for-overlaying-data-onto-an-image-in-r).

the problem I am having is the graph is not a graphical object with a fixed url, but rather, created by code. I don't really understand the code behind the image, but have been unable to scrape recreate it using RCurl and XML.

I see two possible options: using R to launch a browser and save image as
or processing properly the code, I imagine somehow like this

```
URL<-"http://
test<-htmlParese(getURL(url))
xpathSApply(
```

any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link to the image you want to scrape is not an "xml image".  It is simply a .png file.  So, it suffices to save the image to a file, load it into R, and then put it on the plot.  Something like this will get you there, but you'll need to play with it a bit to make it pretty.

```
library(png)
# use the URL from your post, or construct on-the-fly
url = "http://pulse.blogs.yandex.net/?size=small&charset=utf8&period=20120116-20130116&query0=%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD"
download.file(url,destfile='/tmp/test.png',mode='wb')
xvals=rnorm(10)
yvals=rnorm(10)
# just set up an "empty" plot
plot(xvals,yvals,type='n')
r = readPNG('/tmp/test.png')
# read the help for rasterImage for details
rasterImage(r,-1,-1,1,1)
# plot the points over the image
points(xvals,yvals)
```

Comment: Did it work for you? I get this error message     Warning message:
In download.file(url, destfile = "test.png") :
  downloaded length 33784 != reported length 200

Comment: which is followed by the error: Error in readPNG("test.png") : file is not in PNG format. It seems the files downloaded like that are corrupted, and marginally larger than just using 'save as'

Comment: Code works perfectly, all it needed was `download.file(url,destfile='test.png',mode="wb")`

Comment: Edited to reflect Rolf's comment about mode='wb'.